# Comparer example from A. Freeman Pro ASP.NET Core 6 book

Tags: c#

Trying to educate myself on C# I’m reading a book by A. Freeman "Pro ASP.NET Core 6". Here’s an example from the book (p.133) that I simplified down to console app to better understand what’s going on

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
               {
                 new Product { Name = "Kayak", Price = 275M },
                 new Product { Name = "Kayak", Price = 48.95M}
               };
        Comparer.Get<Product>((p1, p2) => p1?.Name == p2?.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(Comparer.Equals(products[0], products[1]));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class Comparer
{
    public static Comparer<U?> Get<U>(Func<U?, U?, bool> func)
    {
        return new Comparer<U?>(func);
    }
}
public class Comparer<T> : Comparer, IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T?, T?, bool> comparisonFunction;
    public Comparer(Func<T?, T?, bool> func)
    {
        comparisonFunction = func;
    }
    public bool Equals(T? x, T? y)
    {
        return comparisonFunction(x, y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}


public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public static Product[] GetProducts()
    {
        Product kayak = new Product
        {
            Name = "Kayak",
            Price = 275M
        };
        Product lifejacket = new Product
        {
            Name = "Lifejacket",
            Price = 48.95M
        };
        return new Product[] { kayak, lifejacket };
    }
}
```

How I think about this is obviously wrong, but I can’t figure out what exactly is not right about it. Here are my thoughts:
Lamba experssion

```
Comparer.Get<Product>((p1, p2) => p1?.Name == p2?.Name);
```

defines a function that will be called here

```
Console.WriteLine(Comparer.Equals(products[0], products[1]))
```

via Comparer’s method

```
 public bool Equals(T? x, T? y)
    {
        return comparisonFunction(x, y);
    }
```

but that is not what seems to happen.
What’s wrong about my thinking?

Comment: What is happening?  We don't know what your thoughts are.  You didn't clarify what the problem is.  Ask us a question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Here is my question asked in another manner. Why the result the code produces is "false" whereas product[0].name equals to product[1].name?

Comment: Careful with string equality. "==" is not "Equals" when it comes to strings. But if you want to check what is actually being called, throw a breakpoint in and step through in the debugger.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the Equals() method and note how it never gets called.  Why Comparer.Equals() does not generate a compile error is hard to explain, looks to me you found a bug in the compiler.  Fix it by using the return value of Comparer.Get(), like var cmp = Comparer.Get(...); Console.WriteLine(cmp.Equals(...));

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by Hans Passant is below. It solves the problem

```
    public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product[] products = new Product[]
               {
                 new Product { Name = "Kayak", Price = 275M },
                 new Product { Name = "Kayak", Price = 48.95M}
               };

        var cmp = Comparer.Get<Product>((p1, p2) => p1?.Name == p2?.Name);
        var eq = cmp.Equals(products[0], products[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(eq);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
 public class Comparer
{
    public static Comparer<U?> Get<U>(Func<U?, U?, bool> func)
    {
        return new Comparer<U?>(func);
    }
}
  public class Comparer<T> : Comparer, IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private Func<T?, T?, bool> comparisonFunction;
    public Comparer(Func<T?, T?, bool> func)
    {
        comparisonFunction = func;
    }
    public bool Equals(T? x, T? y)
    {
        return comparisonFunction(x, y);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}


public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public static Product[] GetProducts()
    {
        Product kayak = new Product
        {
            Name = "Kayak",
            Price = 275M
        };
        Product lifejacket = new Product
        {
            Name = "Lifejacket",
            Price = 48.95M
        };
        return new Product[] { kayak, lifejacket };
    }
}
```